# Getting error when install mysql-server on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxmox

Can Anyone help me with the issue, I am facing error when install mysql server on ubuntu 20.04. I hve tried with the following commands and re-install again but same error i faced.

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

```
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Warning: Unable to start the server.
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
* mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-11-29 05:04:08 UTC; 4ms ago
    Process: 3889 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    **Process: 3897 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)**
   Main PID: 3897 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server shutdown complete"
        CPU: 388ms
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
**E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)**


Please help me out with the solution if anyone sorted this issue. Thank you.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enable nesting in Proxmox container configuration (Options>Features)

Comment: By default nesting is 1 hope it's enabled.